# How to install PyObjC on Python 3.5 (OS X 10.10 Yosemite)?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pyobjc

I am trying to install PyObjC using `pip3 install pyobjc-core`, on a Mac with Python 3.5 and OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite). I get the following error message:

```
Collecting pyobjc-core
  Downloading pyobjc-core-3.1.1.tar.gz (2.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 481kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info
    writing include/pyobjc-compat.h to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/include/pyobjc-compat.h
    writing include/pyobjc-api.h to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/include/pyobjc-api.h
    writing pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing namespace_packages to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-dzm544zy/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 696, in <module>
        **parse_package_metadata()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-dzm544zy/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 371, in run
        egg_info.egg_info.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 180, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 291, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 130, in add_defaults
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-dzm544zy/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 525, in finalize_options
        universal_newlines=True).strip()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 711, in run
        output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-version', '-sdk', 'macosx', 'Path']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-dzm544zy/pyobjc-core/
```

Similar, if I try just to do `pip3 install pyobjc`, I get a similar trackback, ending with these fatal words:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-432fq8a3/pyobjc-core/
```

Any hope for me, or is there, for instance, some known incompatibility with the system bundled version of Python?

Comment: There are no ideas? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a month late here but the first line of the error is:

`xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

You need to install the full version of xcode from the app store not just the command line tools.  :)

Comment: Oh... I will try that and see it it works. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: So, It will be necessary to have full Xcode in every computer that the Python/PyObjC app will need to run, right? Its a big download (3.8GB in this machine), I will need to consider if this is really a good idea for me.

Comment: It depends.  Xcode is compiling PyObjC for your machine.  If you use py2app or similar you'll be bundling this compiled version with your app and the user will not need Xcode (or even pip) installed on their machine.    If you are putting a package up on PyPi (like ```rumps```) then your users will need to install PyObjC to install your package with pip.

Comment: OK, I get it. Now, the thing is... I can't even download the Xcode version for Yosemite I would need for this machine. At least from the App Store. Got to try it in another Mac that has El Capitan.

Comment: You have to jump through some hoops but you can download old versions of Xcode here:https://developer.apple.com/downloads/   EDIT:  If I can't post links then... Go to developer.apple.com and login go to Download Tools and then on the Bottom left is a a link to download Old versions of XCode

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got Xcode now. But there are still errors. I was able to install pyobjc-core, but while installing pyobjc I get a new error... `building 'Foundation._Foundation' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/pyobjc-include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c Modules/_Foundation.m -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/Modules/_Foundation.o -DPyObjC_BUILD_RELEASE=1010`

Comment: `In file included from Modules/_Foundation.m:15:
    Modules/_Foundation_protocols.m:14:28: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSProgressReporting'
        p = PyObjC_IdToPython(@protocol(NSProgressReporting)); Py_XDECREF(p);
                               ^
    Modules/_Foundation_protocols.m:15:28: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSURLSessionStreamDelegate'
        p = PyObjC_IdToPython(@protocol(NSURLSessionStreamDelegate)); Py_XDECREF(p);`

Comment: `    2 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-8jvgwb41/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-lu91snkc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" `

Comment: `failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v0/bzvt8grs6mv33_j13_wdwqs80000gr/T/pip-build-8jvgwb41/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/`

Comment: I believe this could be a different issue, but I have no idea of how to solve it...

Comment: I was able to install it in another Mac after installing Xcode. Must be something specific to the first computer, or its OS version... I will give it another shot soon.